# How can I map a very complicated json data into object by jackson in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I know how to do that until "something".
And I also want to get object by the index of "something".
It's really diffcult >_<.

```
{
  "ResultSet": {
    "0": {
      "Result": {
        "0": {something}
        "1": {something}
        "2": {something}
        .
        .
        .
        .
      }
}
```

Now I created class like this:

ResultSet .java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class ResultSet {
    @JsonProperty("0")
    private Index index;
}
```

Index.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class Index {
    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private Result result;
}
```

Result.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class Result {
    @JsonProperty("0")
    private ItemIndex itemIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON looks like a generic serialization of tabular data, e.g. SQL `ResultSet`, where the *"fields"* of object "ResultSet" are actually row numbers (zero-based), and the *"fields"* of object "Result"` are actually column numbers (zero-based).

With dynamic field names like that, using a JSON object mapper, you should probably just map the data into `Map` objects, where the field names become the map keys.

```
class ResultSet {
    @JsonProperty("ResultSet")
    Map<String, Result> resultMap;
}

class Result {
    @JsonProperty("Result")
    Map<String, Something> somethingMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really awesome. But I want to get the json with RestTemplate, how can I deal with it?